# Want to perform Archive functionality using gmail api

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail-api

I am working on a app using gmail api.
I want to perform archive functionality.
I had gone through the api https://developers.google.com/gmail/api but unable to find any desired solutions.

Can anyone suggest me any solution for the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/) on how to archive espcially the [`moveThreadToArchive(thread)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#moveThreadToArchive(GmailThread)), [`moveThreadsToArchive(threads)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#moveThreadsToArchive(GmailThread)) and [`moveToArchive()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#moveToArchive()). The examples are not in Objective-C, but I think the resource are the same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[A archived message](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576?hl=en) is just a message that lies in the `All Mail` (which isn't an actual label). You can achieve this by removing the `INBOX`-label on the message (or any other label you have added to it), which can be achieved with [modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify).

Comment: `(or any other label you have added to it)` This doesn't seem right. If there is a STARRED message and you archive it, the STARRED label won't be removed. It feels the Archive function is just based on the INBOX label.

Answer (score 1):

```
  C# Code for Gmail APIs Archive email by using OAuth 2.0 service.   
     class ReadAllMails
      {       
        static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom };
        static string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          UserCredential credential;
          using (var stream =
          new FileStream("credentials_dev.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
          {
               string credPath = "token_MailGoogleCom.json";
               credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
               GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
               Scopes,
               "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;                      
             }

            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            }); 

            List<string> lableIds = new List<string>();
            lableIds.Add("INBOX");
            ModifyMessageRequest mods = new ModifyMessageRequest();
            mods.RemoveLabelIds= lableIds;
            service.Users.Messages.Modify(mods, "me", emailId).Execute();
            //emailId that you want to archive
       }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain the answer, rather than just posting code.

Comment: I used the following link to activate my Gmail API https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet. Then I used 
 modify service present inside the GmailService.User.Message.Modify to remove the label INBOX  from the message to move the current mail to archive.